# Properly display web map in sliding sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arcgis-js-api

Using ArcGis Javascript 3.17 API from [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_simple.html), I'm trying to set up a "hideable" web map from the bottom, but it is behaving far from expected, it won't load properly and keeps expanding non stop

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/83jdovv6/7

Libs :

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js

https://js.arcgis.com/3.17

Html :

```
<div>
  <h1 class="big-text"> 
  Test Application
  </h1>
</div>

<div id="map" class="down">
  <i><img id="up_button" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Arrow-up-navmenu.png"></i>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var map;

require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo", //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
    center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
    zoom: 13
  });
});



$('#row').click(function() {

  if ($("#row").hasClass("down")) {
    $("#row").removeClass("down");
    $("#row").animate({
      height: "50%"
    }, 600);

  } else {

    $("#row").animate({
      height: 28
    }, 350);
    $("#row").addClass("down");
  }

});
```

CSS :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(https://pcbx.us/beoh.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.big-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  font-family: pt sans narrow;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 4em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: pt sans narrow;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

#container {
  background: #303030;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#map {
  background: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 28;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

It's worth nothing that I'm a begginer web developer, most of this code I found online

Or alternatively, if someone could recommend a JQuery sliding sidebar plugin that would work in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out few things in your jsfiddle...

- `Esri CSS` was not added because of that map was not loading properly
- `Id and classes` were not used properly.

Below is the proper working solution:

***JSFiddle:*** https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/83jdovv6/11/

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Comment: I eventually figured that's what was missing, but thanks anyways friend!